# Magento 2, Time is incorrect in Admin Grid

Tags: magento2, timezone, time

I use Magento 2.4.1. I have a problem with admin grid.

In my edit form, I set Booking From is: 18:30:00 and Booking To is: 19:30:00 at timezone GMT+7.

When I save, from, to are saved correctly to database, but in my grid, From, To is shown like image below:
[image]

I have no idea to solve it, please help me. Thanks a lot and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Change the timezone in the locale settings for the default scope - https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/locale-options.html</strike>

---

***Later edit***

It just occurred to me that **this has to do with the way the code is written and not a matter of configuration**. Normally, when you add items to the database, **the time added on the record should be in UTC time** and not relative to any timezone.

This should be done this way so that it could accommodate any number of timezones in the areas where the data is visualized (admin or frontend).

You also mentioned

> In my edit form, I set Booking From is: 18:30:00 and Booking To is: 19:30:00 at timezone GMT+7.
> When I save, from, to are saved correctly to database (...)

If the code was written properly, in the database, you should see the time like this:

```
booking from: 11:30
booking to: 12:30
```

and not the actual times 18:30 and 19h30. **The conversion to these times to your timezones should be done only when reading the data, not when writing it to the database.**

So you need to change the code which adds the records to the database and make sure it adds the time relative to UTC standard.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working :(

Comment: please check the update on my answer. i think i know what's going on in there :)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be somewhat related to the Admin locale setting?
[image]

Comment: I changed, but not work :(